# Passing char** parameter char[][] array: C

Tags: c

For below code how do I pass `char[][]` as `char**` parameter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void fn(int argc,char** argv)
{
 int i=0;   
 printf("argc : %d\n",argc);
 for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
     printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
}

int main()
{
char var3[3][10]={"arg1","argument2","arg3"};
char var4[4][10]={"One","Two","Three","Four"};

fn(3,&var3);
fn(4,&var4);


return 0;
}
```

Getting below error:

```
$ gcc -Wall anyNumberOfParameters.c -o anyNumberOfParameters.exe
anyNumberOfParameters.c: In function ‘main’:
anyNumberOfParameters.c:18:1: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fn’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 fn(3,&var3);
 ^
anyNumberOfParameters.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[3][10]’
 void fn(int argc,char** argv)
      ^
anyNumberOfParameters.c:19:1: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fn’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 fn(4,&var4);
 ^
anyNumberOfParameters.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[4][10]’
 void fn(int argc,char** argv)
      ^
```

If I change my code in `main()` as:

```
char* var3[3]={"arg1","argument2","arg3"};
char* var4[4]={"One","Two","Three","Four"};

fn(3,var3);
fn(4,var4);
```

It works fine, but I want to know how do I pass `char[][]` as parameter.

```
char var[3][10]={"One","Two","Three"};
printf("%s",var[1]);
```

it does print : `Two`
So if I pass `var` to `char**` ; won't it be equivalent to two dimentional array's address?

I mean for a function `fn(char*)` we do pass as:

```
char name[20]="Thomas";
fn(name);
```

`char**` is making me confused

Comment: The suggested duplicate is a C++ question; this is a C question

Comment: Hint: print the size of `var3` and `var4`. Another hint: in-memory layout of `char**` and `char[][]` are different.

Comment: I do not know why negative vote? It is a valid question and I received good explanation.. It would be helpful for any beginner.. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you dereference a `char **`, you should get a pointer to `char`. There are no pointers in a `char[3][10]`. They're just not interchangeable.

It works for a one-dimensional `char *` array because the array name implicitly converts to a pointer to the first element in this context, and if you dereference a `char *` you get a `char`, and that's exactly what your one-dimensional `char` array contains.

The line of thinking that "if it works for a one-dimensional array, shouldn't it work for a two-dimensional array?" is just invalid, here.

To make what you want to do work, you'd have to create `char *` arrays, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fn(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("argc : %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char * var3[3] = { "arg1", "argument2", "arg3" };
    char * var4[4] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };

    fn(3, var3);
    fn(4, var4);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./carr
argc : 3
arg1
argument2
arg3
argc : 4
One
Two
Three
Four
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

An alternative is to declare your function as accepting an array of (effectively a pointer to) 10-element arrays of `char`, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fn(int argc, char argv[][10]) {
    printf("argc : %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char var3[3][10] = { "arg1", "argument2", "arg3" };
    char var4[4][10] = { "arg1", "argument2", "arg3", "arg4" };

    fn(3, var3);
    fn(4, var4);

    return 0;
}
```

but this obviously requires hard-coding the sizes of all dimensions except the leftmost, which is usually less desirable and flexible. `char argv[][10]` in the parameter list here is another way of writing `char (*argv)[10]`, i.e. declaring `argv` as a pointer to array of `char` of size `10`.

Answer (score 1):

A `type**` is by definition a pointer to a pointer, or an array of pointers.

When used in a function declaration, `type[][]` is inteligible with `type**` as in:

```
int main(int argc, char argv[][]) { ...
```

But it is not when declaring variables. When you do this:

```
char var[a][b] = { ... }
```

This is a matrix of `char` and there are no pointers envolved here. The compiler pretty much handles this as a straight forward array of `char var[a*b]` and when you access `var[1][2]` it internally does `var[1*b+2]`. It is not really an array of strings, and its utilization is only possible because the compiler knows the value of `b` when compiling this function, as the variable was declared there.

In order to pass as `char**`, `var` must be an array of pointers. A list containing pointers of `char*`.

When you do this:

```
char *var[a] { ... }
```

Now you are telling the compiler your intention. `var` is no longer a matrix of `char`, it is truly a list of pointers `char*`.